# RecyclerView within a ViewPager unpopulated despite Adapter containing data

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-viewpager

I'm currently using a `ViewPager` and `TabLayout` for a couple of similar fragments. The fragments hosted within the ViewPager all have a `RecyclerView`. When I swipe more than one page over, the Fragment (I think?) is destroyed. When I swipe back it's recreated.

Upon debugging, I found that the adapter within the Fragment is non null and populated with the data from before. However, once the fragment is visible it no longer displays any entries.

Here's a video of what's going on. [image]

This is a fragment within the ViewPager

```
class ArtistListFragment : Fragment(), ListView {

    override val title: String
        get() = "Artists"

    private val artistList: RecyclerView by lazy { artist_list }
    @Inject lateinit var api: SaddleAPIManager

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
            = container?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_artist)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        artistList.apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            if (adapter == null) {
                adapter = ViewTypeAdapter(mapOf(AdapterConstants.ARTIST to ArtistDelegateAdapter()))
            }
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("artist")) {
                (adapter as ViewTypeAdapter).setItems(savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList<Artist>("artists"))
            }
        }

        (activity?.application as SaddleApplication).apiComponent.inject(this)
        refreshData()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(
                "artists",
                (artistList.adapter as ViewTypeAdapter).items as ArrayList<out Parcelable>
        )
    }

    private fun refreshData() = launch(UI) {
        val result = withContext(CommonPool) { api.getArtists() }
        when(result) {
            is Success -> (artistList.adapter as ViewTypeAdapter).setItems(result.data.results)
            is Failure -> Snackbar.make(artistList, result.error.message ?: "Error", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

}
```

This is the Fragment hosting the ViewPager

```
class NavigationFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewPager: ViewPager by lazy { pager }
    private val tabLayout: TabLayout by lazy { tab_layout }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
            = container?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewPager.apply {
            adapter = NavigationPageAdapter(childFragmentManager)
        }

        tabLayout.apply {
            setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
        }
    }
}
```

The adapter I'm using for paging

```
class NavigationPageAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

    companion object {
        const val NUM_PAGES = 4
    }

    private val pages: List<Fragment> = (0 until NUM_PAGES).map {
        when (it) {
            0 -> ArtistListFragment()
            1 -> AlbumListFragment()
            2 -> TrackListFragment()
            else -> PlaylistListFragment()
        } as Fragment
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = pages[position]

    override fun getCount(): Int = NUM_PAGES

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? = (pages[position] as ListView).title
}
```

I've tried overriding `onSaveInstanceState` and reading the information from the bundle. It doesn't seem to do anything. The problem seems to actually be the RecyclerView displaying? It's populated with data which is why I'm stumped.

Comment: Did you try using ViewModel of Android Architecture.

Comment: No, but my next task is to implement MVVM after I figure this out. Ultimately that doesn't solve the problem though because I don't want to be hitting the API every time the fragment get's recreated.

Comment: You don't hit the API Everytime using ViewModel. ViewModel lets you survive configuration changes. So that might work.. IMO

Comment: Implementing ViewModel with LiveData didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `setOffscreenPageLimit` for `ViewPager` to keep containing fragments as below:

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(NavigationPageAdapter.NUM_PAGES)
```

Comment: This works, but I'm wondering what the consequences are of this? This application is going to be a mobile music player. The tabs could each have tens of thousands of items in them. I imagine they would be kept alive in memory?

Comment: If you use RecyclerView to show items in fragments, there is no concern about having much items in them. In addition, since the number of fragments in ViewPager is low, using setOffscreenPageLimit has no significant memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the problem. While `setOffScreenPageLimit(NavigationAdapter.NUM_PAGES)` did work, I am cautious to use it because of memory consumption concerns.

As it turns out, storing references to views using `lazy` is bad practice. Since `onCreateView` gets called many times in the lifecycle of the `ArtistListFragment` the same view wasn't being referenced that was currently inflated on the screen.

Removing all `lazy` instantiated views and accessing them directly with the Android Extensions solved my problem.